# copy mysql database into firebird/interbase

Tags: mysql, firebird

I have a client that uses the mysql database to enter data, but he wants the data can be read with accurate program that uses the Firebird database.

Is there a solution to move data in mysql to a Firebird database?

Answer (score 0):

May be something like [datapump](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/dbcomparer/dbcomparer.asp)